# Access parent property in jQuery callback

Tags: javascript, jquery

Unsure if I've phrased this correctly, but in the callback how do I reference the controls property of the base class?

This has been bugging me for some time and I usually work around it, but I'd be grateful if anybody can enlighten me on how I should do this properly.

```
var base = function() {
    var controls = {};

    return {
        init: function(c) {
            this.controls = c
        },
        foo: function(args) {
            this.init(args.controls);
            $(this.controls.DropDown).change(function() {
                $(this.controls.PlaceHolder).toggle();
            });
        }
    }
};
```

Much Obliged,

Paul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the power of closures:

```
var base = function() {
    var controls = {};

    return {
        init: function(c) {
                this.controls = c
        },
        foo: function(args) {
                var self = this;

                this.init(args.controls);
                $(this.controls.DropDown).change(function() {
                        $(self.controls.PlaceHolder).toggle();
                });
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Although [closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254200/access-parent-property-in-jquery-callback#254233) are [preferred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254200/access-parent-property-in-jquery-callback#254237), you could also use jquery `bind` to pass an object along:

```
var base = function() {
    var controls = {};

    return {
        init: function(c) {
            this.controls = c
        },
        foo: function(args) {
            this.init(args.controls);
            $(this.controls.DropDown).bind('change', {controls: this.controls}, function(event) {
                $(event.data.controls.PlaceHolder).toggle();
            });
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: I like this approach and I guess if I am using jQuery extensively throughout my code I should make use of the bind method. I may just use closures for a while so that I get used to using it and then once familiar I can use either. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to leverage closures here.

```
var base = function() {
var controls = {};

return {
    init: function(c) {
            this.controls = c
    },
    foo: function(args) {
            this.init(args.controls);
            $(this.controls.DropDown).change(function(controls) {
                    return function(){
                        $(controls.PlaceHolder).toggle();
                    }
            }(this.controls));
    }
}
```

};

Comment: Beat me for a moment with more elegant solution :D

Comment: Something peculiar seems to be happening when I use this approach. The click event fires on page load. I think it has to do with the controls parameter in the callback function because when i remove that the click event doesn't automatically fire.